# SQL - same value in one field in output

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have

Table 1

```
Column A, Column B, Column C, Type, ID
111       ABC       NEW       R    1 
222       LMN       NEW       L    1
```

What I want is the same value for one of the field. So the result should be like -

```
111, ABC, NEW, R, 1
222, ABC, NEW, L, 1
```

The ID is the common value between the two and can be used to link the two records.

To clarify, above is a table I have and I have given the result I expect. Please refer to the column 2 of the result. I would want the value in the column 2 to be the same for the two rows, but rest of the values to reflect the actual value in the table. The common link between the two rows is the ID field.

I think that I must clarify that I dont need the top 1 or the first value. The value in Column B should be the same in the result and must be the value where Type = R. The ID links the two rows and Type drives what value should be shown in Column B. Using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Not sure what specific details can I add. I tried with self join but not able to get the result I have described above. I always get two values for the Column B field in the result. Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code you've tried. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer.

Comment: I don't even understand OPs question, much less see any evidence that they've tried to solve it.

Comment: Im unsure if you are displaying your columns correctly because your result and column are correct but I dont see any SQL code.

Comment: What determines which value you want to see?  For example, I understand that for ID = 1 you want to see ABC... but why does that value win out over LMN?  We need to know this before any attempt at a solution can be made.

Comment: I agree with the above commenters, specifically dazedandconfused.  There doesn't seem to be enough to go on to answer this question.  Select Column A, 'ABC', Column C, Type, ID from tablename where ID=1  would produce the result that the result above, but I'm not sure this is the answer that the asker is looking for.

Comment: How do you decide that ABC should be used twice and not LMN?

Comment: Martin Drautzburg  - based on the value in the Type field. It should be the value of R always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you expect, but seem like you need something like

```
Select A,(SELECT TOP 1 B FROM #Temp WHERE ID=T.ID AND D='R') AS B,C,D,ID
From #Temp T
```

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I think that I must clarify that I dont need the top 1 or the first value. The value in Column B should be the same in the result and must be the value where Type = R. The ID links the two rows and Type drives what value should be shown in Column B

Comment: @cherry: I have updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: huMpty duMpty - Thanks thats exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the first value found in column B for a given id...

```
SELECT 
    A, 
    MIN(B) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS B, 
    C, 
    [Type], 
    ID
FROM 
    Table1
ORDER BY ID, B
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to accomplish this in SQL Server 2012 you can use the FIRST_VALUE() Window Function like:

```
SELECT ColA, FIRST_VALUE(ColB) OVER(ORDER BY ColA /*or the ordering column of the query*/)
FROM Table1
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx

Otherwise you can do a subquery like this:

```
SELECT ColA,
-- returns the first record, add ordering if you want to choose another row
(SELECT ColB FROM Table1 WHERE ColA /*id*/ = (SELECT TOP 1 ColA FROM Table1))    
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Update TableName
SET Column_B = (
        SELECT Column_B
        FROM TableName
        WHERE Column_A=MIN(Column_A)
        )
WHERE ID = 1
```

??